# Multiple context trouble. Can't make two queues (main and private) save data in Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, queue, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I want to set up saving data on private queue of ManagedObjectContext, but can't do it properly.

I've saved data with one context in mainThread and it worked okay. But after when I added **.perform()** and **performAndWait()** functions I can't get my data in SQLite.

I have this function in **CoreDataManager.swift** file:

```
func saveContext() {
        privateObjectContext.perform {
            do {
                try self.privateObjectContext.save()
                self.mainObjectContext.performAndWait {
                    do {
                        try self.mainObjectContext.save()
                    } catch {
                        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
            }
        }
```

And call this function from **Repository.swift** file:

```
func insertQuestProgress(qp: QuestProgress) {
        //here's my code
        CoreDataManager.instance.saveContext()
    }
```

Also in **CoreDataManager.swift** file I initialize variables of privateContext and mainContext like in tons of articles about this topic:

```
private lazy var privateObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.parent = self.mainObjectContext
        return managedObjectContext
    }()

    private lazy var mainObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = CoreDataManager.instance.persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()
```

Maybe it's don't save, because in **insertQuestProgress(qp: QuestProgress)** I create new entity with context of **CoreDataManager.instance.persistentContainer.viewContext**

```
func deleteQuestProgress(id: String) {
        let questProgresses = CoreDataManager.instance.fetchQuestprogress()
        guard let questProgress = questProgresses.first(where: {$0.questId == id}) else {return}
        CoreDataManager.instance.persistentContainer.viewContext.delete(questProgress)
        CoreDataManager.instance.saveContext()
    }

    func insertQuestProgress(qp: QuestProgress) {
        if let quest = getQuestProgressEntityById(id: qp.questId){
            quest.qpJson = converter.toJson(value: qp)
        }
        else{
            let questProgress = QuestProgressEntity(context: CoreDataManager.instance.persistentContainer.viewContext)
            questProgress.questId = qp.questId
            questProgress.qpJson = converter.toJson(value: qp)
        }
        CoreDataManager.instance.saveContext()
    }
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just from a first glance, it seems like you got your contexts backwards. Your main object context should be the one you save to asynchronously, and the private context, on a private queue, should synchronously save. Try something like this:

```
    // Parent context, will save things on a private queue synchronously.
    private lazy var privateContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return moc
    }()

    // Child context, should be used asynchronously.
    private(set) lazy var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        moc.parent = privateContext
        return moc
    }()

    func saveContext() {
        mainObjectContext.perform {
            do {
                try self.mainObjectContext.save()
                self.privateObjectContext.performAndWait {
                    do {
                        try self.privateObjectContext.save()
                    } catch {
                        print("Failure to save context: \(error)")
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print("Failure to save context: \(error)")
            }
        }
```

This may not be your *exact* problem, but if you're still having issues you may need to post more code re: exactly *what* content it is you're saving.

(Also, consider not throwing `fatalError()` if your save fails. Crashing your app isn't great UX - better to inform the user and/or retry saving.)

Answer (score 0):

It was quite simple.
Function **saveContext()** from **CoreDataManager.swift** file:

```
func saveContext() {
        managedContext.performAndWait {
            do {
                try self.managedContext.save()
            } catch {
                print("Failure to save context: \(error)")
            }
        }
        privateContext.perform {
            do {
                try self.privateContext.save()
            } catch {
                print("Failure to save context: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

I put off **privateContext.perform()** from **managedContext.performAndWait()** block.
Moreover, I changed **CoreDataManager.instance.persistentContainer.viewContext** to **CoreDataManager.instance.managedContext** which is my context (lazy variable)
And it works! :)